# Hadoop single node configuration on the high memory machine

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a single node instance of Apache Hadoop 1.1.1 with default parameter values (see e.g. [[1]](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/core-default.html) and [[2]](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/mapred-default.html)) on the machine with a lot of RAM and very limited free disk space size. Then, I notice that this Hadoop instance wastes a lot of disk space during map tasks. What configuration parameters should I pay attention to in order to take advantage of high RAM capacity and decrease disk space usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use several of the mapred.* params to compress map output, which will greatly reduce the amount of disk space needed to store mapper output. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571156/hadoop-how-to-compress-mapper-output-but-not-the-reducer-output) for some good pointers.

Note that different compression codecs will have different issues (i.e. GZip needs more CPU than LZO, but you have to install LZO yourself). [This page](http://cloudtimes.org/2011/05/24/hadoop-compression-the-elephant-thats-not-in-the-room/) has a good discussion of compression issues in Hadoop, although it is a bit dated.

The amount of RAM you need depends upon what you are doing in your map-reduce jobs, although you can increase your heap-size in:

```
conf/mapred-site.xml mapred.map.child.java.opts
```

See [cluster setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html) for more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dfs.datanode.du.reserved` in hdfs-site.xml to specify an amount of disk space you won't use.  I don't know whether hadoop is able to compensate with higher memory usage.

You'll have a problem, though, if you run a mapreduce job that's disk i/o intensive.  I don't think any amount of configuring will help you then.