# Hadoop - Save space and multi-input issue

Tags: java, hadoop, maven-2, compression, mapreduce

Okay so I am quite new to Hadoop and have written a task which essentially processes 2 folders of gzipped files to see if the total content is equal.

However my first run of my job failed at 30% because it ran out of space on the file system (which I cannot expand), so I looked into compression and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571156/hadoop-how-to-compress-mapper-output-but-not-the-reducer-output?rq=1) which led me to try snappy, however as I am forced to use hadoop 0.2 it does not recognise snappy so I thought to try gzip

```
conf.setBoolean("mapred.output.compress", true);
conf.set("mapred.output.compression.type", CompressionType.BLOCK.toString());
conf.setClass("mapred.output.compression.codec", GzipCodec.class, CompressionCodec.class);
conf.setBoolean("mapred.compress.map.output", true);
conf.set("mapred.map.output.compression.type", CompressionType.BLOCK.toString());
conf.setClass("mapred.map.output.compression.codec", GzipCodec.class, CompressionCodec.class);
```

but then I get:

> java.io.IOException: not a gzip file
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.BuiltInGzipDecompressor.processBasicHeader(BuiltInGzipDecompressor.java:490)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.BuiltInGzipDecompressor.executeHeaderState(BuiltInGzipDecompressor.java:254)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.BuiltInGzipDecompressor.decompress(BuiltInGzipDecompressor.java:183)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:89)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:83)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.wrappedReadForCompressedData(IOUtils.java:170)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Reader.readData(IFile.java:342)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Reader.rejigData(IFile.java:373)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Reader.readNextBlock(IFile.java:357)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Reader.next(IFile.java:389)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$Segment.next(Merger.java:220)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Merger.java:420)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Merger.java:381)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.merge(Merger.java:60)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:414)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:309)

from reading around I believe this to be because none of the hadoop compression algorithms can compress the map output from multiple input files. No doubt I will need to compress the output as well but considering that never even starts at the moment I would be happy to make any progress at all.

So now is when I turn to the Internet for help, is there anything else I can do to reduce this footprint, I really need compression because I am dealing with around 20GB input and I only have 50GB to play with on my single node cluster (I am currently doing this in the testing environment, hence the single node and cannot test with more resources until I can show it working because I can't kill the production cluster).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.